# What is the most "unbalanced" vector between two given vectors?

Tags: algorithms

Let $\mathbb{R}_+$ be the set of non-negative real numbers. Let $m$ be a positive integer and $\leq_m$ be the product order on $\mathbb{R}_+^m$. Lastly, given a vector $V = (v_1, \dots, v_m) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ we denote $d(V)$ the "balanced degree" of $V$ defined as $d(V) = \sum_{i=1}^m{|v_i - avg(V)|}$ where $avg(V) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m{v_i}}{m}$. For example, if $V = (3, 6, 10, 1)$, then $avg(V) = 5$ and $d(V) = |3 - 5| + |6 - 5| + |10 - 5| + |1 - 5| = 2 + 1 + 5 + 4 = 12$. Intuitively, $d(V)$ represents the Manhattan distance between $V$ and the "average" line $(x_1, \dots, x_m) \subseteq \mathbb{R}_+^m$ of equation $x_1 = \dots = x_m$.

Given two vectors $V, V' \in \mathbb{R}^m_+$ such that $V \leq_m V'$, is there an efficient way to compute the number $f(V, V') = \max\{d(W) \mid V \leq_m W \leq_m V'\}$? Intuitively, this number corresponds to the highest distance from a vector $W$ situated between $V$ and $V'$ to the "average" line, such a vector $W$ being thus the most "unbalanced" vector between $V$ and $V'$.

For example, if $V = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ and $V' = (4, 10, 2, 10, 4)$, such a furthest vector $W$ seems to be the vector $W = (0, 10, 0, 10, 0)$ with $d(W) = 24$.

Ideally, I need an efficient (polytime) algorithm to compute such a number given the two vectors $V, V'$.